# Calculated a value in child of nested json and add it as a new elements to the original nested json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have following json:

```
click: false
image: "xxxx"
  items: Array(4)
  0:
    click: false
    image: "xxxx/chapter.png"
    items: Array(12)
        0:
         click: true
         courseID: 1
         coverImage:"xxxxx"
         duration: "(2':20)"
         image: "xxxx/chapter.png"
         pdfLinkIos:"xxxxx"
         title: "Motion title"
         videoLink: "xxxx"
        _internalId: "MV6ZgJ_BxxeD"
```

and I want to add an elements that calculated with an Async function. The calculation should execute for the levels that has the "click:true". I could parse the function successfully and I could calculate it correctly even. 
Here is my code:

```
       parseValues=(obj)=> {
          for(var k in obj) {
              if(obj[k] instanceof Object) {
                  this.parseValues(obj[k]);
              } else {
                console.log("[coverRnder] all", k, );
                  if(obj["click"]){ 
                    return this.accumulateRating(obj).then(rating => {
                        obj.push(rate: rating);
                    });
                  //obj[k].push("");
                  }
              }
          }              
      };

  async accumulateRating(node) {
     return;
  }
```

My only problem is that I don't know how to add the calculated elements to my original json to its proper level. (this.state.courseContent). 
In fact, what I need is to have the output of `accumulateRating` in my original json with title of rate as below:

```
  click: false
    image: "xxxx"
      items: Array(4)
      0:
        click: false
        image: "xxx"
        items: Array(12)
            0:
             click: true
             courseID: 1
             coverImage:"xxxxxx"
             duration: "(2':20)"
             image: "xxxx"
             pdfLinkIos:"xxxxxx"
             title: "Motion title"
             videoLink: "xxxx"
            _internalId: "MV6ZgJ_BxxeD"
             rate: 3.5
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: You are not posting objects but console dumps. Perhaps use `[<>]` snippet editor to create a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan: Thanks for your answer. I tired to push inside Amy json, but I couldn't do it. I make it minimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push()` is for Arrays not Objects. To add a key/value pair to an Object you can just define it.

```
return this.accumulateRating(obj).then(rating => {
    obj.rate = rating;
    //obj["rate"] = rating; also works
});
```